# In Fabrik forcing csv to export only whats on screen

Tags: php, jquery, csv, joomla, export-to-csv

I'm using "fabrik" fabrikar(dot)com to display table list. The data has join statement and I'm using filters with toggle columns. The toggle function hides columns in list. When I'm exporting the list the hidden columns are exported too. The question is "Is there an way to export only what we see on screen?".